# my nas fails to mount on boot what is wrong with my fstab entry

Tags: mount, fstab

I have finally dumped all of my Windows systems and moved them all onto Linux Mint. Having solved the nonsense that is getting a modern all-in-one printer scanner to function I have now moved onto connecting my NAS. My problem is the age-old one of not mounting at boot time. If I issue a `sudo mount -a` once the system is up it mounts fine but never at boot. My `fstab` entry and various logs are shown below. What is wrong with it please.

## from fstab

```
# mount my Nas
//192.168.0.12/Public /home/mike/Nas cifs rw,guest,vers=1.0,iocharset=utf8,_netdev,noperm 0 0
```

## from boot.log

```
[  OK  ] Started Network Manager Wait Online.
[  OK  ] Reached target Network is Online.
         Mounting /home/mike/Nas...
         Starting /etc/rc.local Compatibility...
[  OK  ] Started /etc/rc.local Compatibility.
[FAILED] Failed to mount /home/mike/Nas.
See 'systemctl status home-mike-Nas.mount' for details.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Remote File Systems.
         Starting Permit User Sessions...
```

## from `/etc/mtab` after issuing `sudo mount -a`

```
$ tail -1 /etc/mtab
//192.168.0.12/Public /home/mike/Nas cifs rw,relatime,vers=1.0,
sec=none,cache=strict,domain=,uid=0,noforceuid,
gid=0,noforcegid,addr=192.168.0.12,file_mode=0755,
dir_mode=0755,nounix,serverino,mapposix,noperm,rsize=61440,
wsize=65536,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1 0 0
```

Comment: Are you able to get it to mount without using the guest user? I've always had issues with guest working properly. Try mounting it with a specific user. You can do this by using putting this after your mount location: `user,username=yourusername,credentials=/etc/somefile 0 0`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have all the correct permissions and add a `UID` to your `fstab` entry.

`//192.168.0.12/Public /home/mike/Nas cifs rw,guest,uid=myuser,vers=1.0,iocharset=utf8,_netdev,noperm 0 0`

CIFS is pretty bad with users, especially when it gets mounted. Most of the time it will mount with "nobody" as the user and group. Depending on the permissions, you might need to add a `UID` AND and `GID` to your `fstab` entry.

Comment: I would not used vers=1.0 nowadays, it is becoming obsolete as we speak.

Comment: Yeah good point -- I should have maybe corrected that as well in his line.